# how remove last special character from this string with preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex

I want to remove this `>`

from

```
com.gau.go.launcherex.gowidget.weatherwidget>
```

Comment: Is it always the last character in the string? You can just `rtrim()` it if so.

Comment: rtrim(); not work with speacial charecter

Comment: It will work, you just need to specify which characters to trim. `rtrim($string, '>');` If you don't provide the second argument, it will only trim whitespace.

Comment: please write some code you tried to solve your problem before asking on SO

Comment: What is "special" about `>`, and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

To remove `>` you can use `preg_replace()` as

```
preg_replace('/[>$]/s', '', $str);
```

**Output**

```
com.gau.go.launcherex.gowidget.weatherwidget
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the character before `$` to match it at the end of the string.

```
$string = preg_replace('/>$/', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove this > im used this code

```
rtrim($string,'&gt');
```